# Strict standards: Declaration of SugarFieldTime::save() should be compatible with SugarFieldBase::save()

Tags: php

I'm getting this error in my code.

Strict standards: Declaration of SugarFieldTime::save() should be compatible with SugarFieldBase::save(&$bean, $params, $field, $properties, $prefix = '') in C:\wamp\www\ArcusCRMDemo\include\SugarFields\Fields\Time\SugarFieldTime.php on line 95

I'm also checked the visibility and parameters list and initial value.

***My source Code :***

**SugarFieldBase.php**

```
public function save(&$bean, $params, $field, $properties, $prefix = '')
{
    if (isset($params[$prefix . $field])) {
        if (isset($properties['len']) && isset($properties['type']) && $this->isTrimmable($properties['type'])) {
            $bean->$field = trim($this->unformatField($params[$prefix . $field], $properties));
        } else {
            $bean->$field = $this->unformatField($params[$prefix . $field], $properties);
        }
    }
}
```

**SugarFieldTime.php**

```
   function save(&$bean, $params, $field, $properties, $prefix = '') {
        global $timedate;
        if ( !isset($params[$prefix.$field]) ) {
            $bean->$field = '';
            return;
        }

        $bean->$field = $timedate->to_db_time($params[$prefix.$field], false);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if the issue is the references, but logically it should not be allowed to override a pass by value with a pass by reference. When you call the parent class you have an expectation of immutability of your original variables when passing value types which should be preserved by child classes

Comment: im tried that also but Still that problem cant be resolved

Comment: @Karthik A hint for your future questions, don't use blockquotes if you don't quote anything.

Comment: @matt I cant understand what you telling...

Comment: @Karthik the phrase "I tried that" does not mean anything when I didn't suggest anything for you to try

Comment: @Karthik, it is about the formatting of your question. The text "i am getting this error in my code..." has a yellow background which is a block quote which should be used only for quotes not for standard text. The rest of your formatting is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

The child function is not compatible with the parent function. It should be:

**SugarFieldTime.php**

```
public function save(&$bean, $params, $field, $properties, $prefix = '')
```

Note the `&` are gone from all parameters except `$bean`

The reasoning is as I commented:

When you call the parent class you have an expectation of immutability of your original variables when passing value types which should be preserved by child classes. This is because you can pass a child class masquerading as a parent class object (since the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) holds) and you'd expect all calls to your `save` method to not alter the original contents of `$params` if `$params` is a value type (e.g. int, string, array, float)

Comment: @Karthik **only `$bean`** has that reference. Nothing else

Comment: in addition to your answer, there is a syntax error in the save function in SugarFieldTime.php file: i.e. $bean->$field = ''        
semicolon is missing.

Comment: @AmrinderSingh sorry is Editing mistake in source Code semicolon is present

Comment: @apokryfos yes boss....I tried all of your suggestion But Its Not Resolving

Comment: @Karthik update your question with what you've tried and still did not work

Comment: i changed my current Source code parameters are same data type and also same name...And $bean only having the &ref ...

Comment: @apokryfos i updated the Current Source and getting Error in my question ..You can tell your suggestions

Comment: @Karthik it's working for me. Here's your original code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d15c435e1c959e27850f85d14317fd95fa88bb0) which has the error and here's the updated code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e631f2c8cb51bb75f3849daf2104ec56c60817f2) which doesn't are you using OpCache or XCache or something?

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you its working fine...once i deleted my cache folder then the Error is Fixed

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error though in your save function():

you have used:

```
$bean->$field = ''
```

it should be:

```
 $bean->$field = '';
```

semicolon was missing.

Comment: sorry dude its Editing mistake